# Pasting without indenting the rest of the line - "over" mode

Tags: vim

I didn't title this pasting in "insert" mode (A-la Windows text editors, which is what I mean) or in-place because I don't mean the same as the questions already on SO. What I want is when pasting "Dad" in:

```
Hello |Mom, you are my favorite!
```

where `|` denotes the cursor position in normal mode. I want the result to be:

```
Hello Da|d, you are my favorite!
```

rather then the usual P (for example, p as well):

```
Hello Da|dMom, you are my favorite!
```

Another example - pasting "bla bla bla bla" onto:

```
This is some stuff | that I want to paste on
```

results in

```
This is some stuff bla bla bla bl|apaste on
```

If the length of what I'm pasting exceeds the space left on the line, it should erase everything and continue on the same line, so pasting "la la la" to

```
a | b
```

will result in

```
a la la l|a
```

Comment: A lot of possible ways, are you looking for `vwp` ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Nope, it could be more than a word, I'll update with another example. I want a way, whatever you have.

Comment: Can it be more than one line? What happens if you reach the end of the line and there’s still stuff to paste?

Comment: @Ryan Good point, haven't considered - should continue on the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter replace mode with `R`, press `^R` to put a register, and finally press `"` to select the default register.

(Relevant help: `:help R` and `:help i^R`.)

Comment: I never knew of replace mode! Perfect.